# Two-sample statistical significance test taking into account group membership (proportions) and numeric comparison

Tags: continuous-data, contingency-tables, two-sample

Say I have two samples of observations, S1 and S2, which can be of unequal sizes.  For each observation, I have two variables: G (a categorical group assignment, say it is binary with values A/B), and a numeric variable X.  I would like to formulate a statistical comparison of some sort (either p-values or effect size) that compares the values of X within groups G.  That is, for instance, picture a "contingency table" where rows correspond to value of G being A or B, and the columns being the sample membership S1 or S2.  In each cell are the values of X for each sample corresponding to each group A or B.  I want to say that S1 and S2 differ if the conditional values of X| A, or X| B differ significantly, and/or the proportions of observations in A/B differ between groups.

This situation differs from doing a two-sample test on just X between S1 and S2 because under my test, I would judge that S1 and S2 differ if I constructed S2 by taking the values of X in S1 and changing the group assignments, whereas a simple two-sample test on X here would not.  Also, say for instance all observations had the same value of X, but S1 had half A and half B, and S2 had A be a 1/4 and B be 3/4 of records.  Here again I would want to detect that the samples differ because the group proportions differ between S1 and S2.

Essentially I want to detect a distribution change by combining the groups and X somehow without having to do separate tests on X or Y only (or if there is some way that separate tests could be combined, that is fine).

I also may want to specifically formulate a test in a single direction.  Say for instance "A" signifies a negative aspect like that the observation is an outlier.  And X is an outlier score where higher values indicate outlierness.  Thus I may want to ask, "Is S2 more outlying than S1", i.e. "Does S2 contain a higher proportion of A, and/or higher values of X when G=A, compared to S1"?  Thus for instance, if S2 had a significantly higher proportion of A but its values of X|A were slightly LOWER than in S1, then this could still be significant because the two directions cancel each other out partially.

Any ideas?